# Unable to Redirect Screen Following Deep Link Path on Receiving VoIP Notification When Device is Locked

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking, voip

I am currently working on implementing VoIP call functionality in my React Native app using the CallKeep SDK and React Native Deep linking. The deep linking part is handled using the `linking` object with the `react-navigation` library. However, I am facing an issue when my device is locked and a VoIP notification is received.

The deep link path for the VoIP call is defined in the `linking` object as follows:

```js
const linking = {
  prefixes: ['calling://'],
  config: {
    screens: {
      Call: {
        path: 'Call/:sessionName/:displayName/:roleType/:hasVideo',
      },
      InitialScreen: {
        path: 'InitialScreen',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

When the app is in the background or terminated, and a VoIP notification is received, I expect the app to handle the deep link and redirect the user to the `Call` screen with the appropriate session details. This works fine when the device is unlocked or the app is running in the foreground.

However, when the device is locked, and the VoIP notification is received, tapping on the notification does not redirect the user to the expected `Call` screen. Instead, it opens the app at the `InitialScreen`.

Is there a specific approach or configuration I am missing to handle deep links correctly when the device is locked and the app receives a VoIP notification? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!